# Display of box widget on site

Tags: box-api

i'm using box-widget on my site and my problem is the following: Widget is displayed incorrectly after full page download. If i start working with it during loading everything is fine and it is fully functional after page load. But if i wait for full loading then widget shows message than area of widget is small. (In fact area is bigger then 330x400)
Now widget is available at http://sp-hosting.nichost.ru/pi/index.php/reestr (on the third tab  named ФАЙЛЫ)

Comment: When you generate your iframe code in Box's website, you can see that there are several parameters that are passed in:

    <iframe src="https://app.box.com/embed_widget/a414fda64/s/7epel9evt4j8?view=list&sort=name&direction=ASC&theme=blue" width="400" height="400" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

What are you setting all these fields to?

Comment: <p><iframe src="https://app.box.com/embed_widget/81ce4864db01/s/0uvfnxowa65bwygn1v3a?view=list&amp;sort=name&amp;direction=ASC&amp;theme=blue" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="451"></iframe></p>

Answer (score 0):

The width doesn't accept a %.  So when you send in 100%, I believe that looks like a request for a 100 pixel wide control, which is really too narrow for us to support.  You have to specify # of pixels you want the width to be.

Comment: i tested it on several pages and it works fine. As I understand it is width of iframe and this attribute can be set in pixels or in %. Now i deleted few plugins on other tabs of this page and everything is ok now. Problem is solved.

Comment: The problem is not solved :( if i set iframe size to 700*500 the behavior is the same. While page is not fully loaded i can switch to widget tab and everything is ok. When loading complite message about widget size appear. One more note: right-click menu is not affected by this problem and it shows typical actions